# Macro Excel - How to note errors?

Tags: excel, vba, copy

with this code

```
Public Sub CopiaFile()

Dim Origine  As String
Dim Destinazione As String


Last_Row = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, 
SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

For i = 4 To Last_Row

    Origine = Cells(i, 6)
    Destinazione = Cells(i, 7)

    Set fs = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
    fs.CopyFile Origine, Destinazione
    Set fs = Nothing

Next i


End Sub
```

(as you may understand better than me) I want to copy some file from a path (indicated in row G), to a path (indicated in row H).
At a certain point it started giving me error 76 path not found. But both the origin path and the destination folder exist.

I would like to add some lines that could allow me to:

- skip the line with the error
- note in corrispondance with the line (in row I) that that file wasn't copied

could you help me?

Many thanks

Comment: Put `On Error Resume Next` before loop which will skip error.

Comment: thanks, but then how to know which are the lines (i.e. the files) not copied?

Answer (score 0):

**Edited** and changed file paths checking

from your narrative you have wrong column indexes

furthermore you may instantiate one FSO object for all `CopyFile` methods

you may also want to use `Value2`  property of `Range` object to get its actual plain text content

finally you may want to check for existence of `Origine` file and not existence of `Destinazione` file to actually call `CopyFile` upon them:

```
Public Sub CopiaFile()

    Dim Origine  As String
    Dim Destinazione As String
    Dim Last_Row As Long, i As Long

    Last_Row = ActiveSheet.Cells.Find("*", SearchOrder:=xlByRows, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious).Row

    With CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject") ' instantiate and reference a FSO object
        For i = 4 To Last_Row
            Origine = Cells(i, 7).Value2 ' column index 7-> column G
            Destinazione = Cells(i, 8).Value2 ' column index 8-> column H
            If .FileExists(Origine) And (.folderexists(Destinazione) Or .FileExists(Destinazione)) Then
                .CopyFile Origine, Destinazione
            Else
                Cells(i, 9).Value = "file not copied"
            End If
        Next
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Yes thanks, G and H where simple typos. But i added the lines and the error still comes...

Comment: make sure you are using _my last edited code_ and then tell me what line is actually throwing the error

Comment: Same error, in the first occurrance: it wrote "file not copied" and stopped.

Comment: By debugging it says that the error is here:   .CopyFile Origine, Destinazione. Also, if I restart by modifying for i = 5, it gives me the error at the beginning, without writing file not copied...

Comment: 1) _"By debugging it says that the error is here: .CopyFile Origine, Destinazione"_, and what does the error say in this case?  2) _"Also, if I restart by modifying for i = 5, it gives me the error at the beginning, without writing file not copied.."_ what does _"at the beginning"_ mean? what line is throwing the error in this case?

Comment: 1) Run-time error '76' Path not found  2) same error (at the beginning means that the error is showed up at time 0, without copying any file

Comment: _"2) same error (at the beginning means that the error is showed up at time 0, without copying any file"_, please be more detailed: what line is actually throwing the error _"showed up at time 0"_?

Comment: Yes i'm using it. Line 14 col 1 is the line with the error

Comment: with _"what line is actually throwing the error"_ i mean _code line_, not excel sheet line

Comment: OK. Now no error. But it wrote "file not cpied" on all the rows, but 4 of them.

Comment: this could mean either that the origin doesn't exist (but the file exist) or that the destination folder d'esn't exist, but it exists.

Comment: so step through the code and use Immediate Window (CTRL-G to pop it out) and carefully check the file and/or folder path in `Origine` and `Destinazione`

Comment: No. It's a mistery. Not copied, but the origine file exist, destination folder exist, destination file doesn't exist ....